# How do I populate a listbox with List<string> data

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listbox, named listBox2, that I am trying to populate. 
"ProSailor" is a class and the three numbers at the end are values from said class.

I need to add these values to listBox2.

```
public string[] listBoxBoard = new string[10];
    List<string> _scoreboard = new List<string>();
    ProSailor sailor1 = new ProSailor(1, 24, 7);
    ProSailor sailor2 = new ProSailor(2, 23, 14);
    ProSailor sailor3 = new ProSailor(3, 20, 5);
```

However, if I try this:

```
 _scoreboard.Add(sailor1);
```

I just get two errors that say:

1. The best overloaded method match for
   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(string)' has some
   invalid arguments
2. Argument 1: cannot convert from 'SailingEvent.ProSailor' to 'string'

I have also tried:

```
_scoreboard.Add(listBoxBoard[0]);
```

This doesn't return any errors but does not populate the listbox.

Comment: Passing listboxboard won't do anything because you never assigned values to it.

Comment: You have string generic list not ProSailer type. If you want to achieve that you must override ToString() in ProSailor class or you must create your list like: List<ProSailor> _scoreBoard = new List<ProSailor>();

Comment: I don't see any call to listBox2.add in your code, where is the code the calls this function ? you should be able to add and see the type name in the list box

Answer (score 1):

In your `ProSailer` class you override the `ToString()` Function so the Listbox will know what to display. Add you collection of `ProSailor` to the `Listbox` since it adds items as Objects that includes class objects.

```
 public override string ToString()
  {
   return "your string to display";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting a type mismatch is because you've initialized your list as `List<string>` and then try to add a `ProSailor` type object to the list. If sailor has some string property you could try the following:

say ProSailor looks something like this:

```
    class ProSailor
    {
        public string MyStringProperty { get; set; }

        public ProSailor(int a, int b, int c)
        {
        }
    }
```

then to accomplish what you're doing:

```
            List<ProSailor> sailorList = (new ProSailor[] 
            {
                new ProSailor(1, 24, 7),
                new ProSailor(2, 23, 14),
                new ProSailor(3, 20, 5)
            }).ToList();

            List<string> stringList = sailorList.Select(s => s.MyStringProperty).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class looks like this one:

```
class ProSailor
{
    public ProSailor(int num1, int num2, int num3)
    {
        Num1 = num1;
        Num2 = num2;
        Num3 = num3;
    }

    public int Num1 { get; set; }
    public int Num2 { get; set; }
    public int Num3 { get; set; }
}
```

And you want to get List of string with values you should create new method to get this list:

```
class ProSailor
{
    public ProSailor(int num1, int num2, int num3)
    {
        Num1 = num1;
        Num2 = num2;
        Num3 = num3;    
    }

    public int Num1 { get; set; }
    public int Num2 { get; set; }
    public int Num3 { get; set; }

    public List<string> GetAllValues()
    {
        return new List<string> { Num1.ToString(), Num2.ToString(), Num3.ToString() };
    }
}
```

Now if you want create one List of string and combine values from few object you can use `AddRange` methond:

```
List<string> _scoreboard = new List<string>();
ProSailor sailor1 = new ProSailor(1, 24, 7);
ProSailor sailor2 = new ProSailor(2, 23, 14);
ProSailor sailor3 = new ProSailor(3, 20, 5);

_scoreboard.AddRange(sailor1.GetAllValues());
_scoreboard.AddRange(sailor2.GetAllValues());
_scoreboard.AddRange(sailor3.GetAllValues());
```

Now you can populate your list using following code:

```
listBox2.DataSource = _scoreboard;
```